# Get iTunes URL of MPMediaItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes-store, mpmediaitem, media-library

Is there a way to get the iTunes URL of a `MPMediaItem`? So I can open that song in iTunes?

I would like to be able to have an "open this song in iTunes" option like Shazam does once you have found a song you like.

Thanks

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation on MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys)? It doesn't track that information.

Answer (score 1):

`MPMediaItem` has a property called `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` that should hold the URL you're looking for, at least when you don't have the song available offline, which it sounds like you don't.

Comment: I think this may be deprecated now.  Wonder if anyone has an updated solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the same thing. The only solution I can think of is using [iTunes Search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) based off the title, album, artist, etc on `MPMediaItem`. Far from ideal because results may not match but it works for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10.3, we are able to get a something call playbackStoreID from a MPMediaItem, however, it sometimes return "0" instead of a real media id on iTunes store.

@Marcus Stemple mentioned you can get an url from "MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL", but it is not guarantee to be returned.

I think for now the better way might be using the information you have from a MPMediaItem such as Artist name and track name to make query to the iTunes Search API and then retrieve the most closet result it found.